# How to get the source url for RSS feeds by the Feeds module?

Tags: feeds

When using Feeds for displaying external RSS content on my site, it doesn't work because Feeds turns links like http://externalsite.com/abc into *mysite.com/abc*. Aggregator gives the desired result, i.e. the complete source url *http://externalsite.com/abc*. Can I get the same **automatic** result using Feeds? If yes, how?